# ui-router event.preventDefault won't render the ui-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to redirect to another state on `stateChangeStart` but `event.preventDefault` and `$state.go()` are not able to render the view. If I comment out both of them, it'll start working. Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IZOWWNIKtAmNBZ9rmSVb?p=preview):

```
var example = angular.module("example", ['ui.router']);

example.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("root", {
            url: "/",
            abstract: true,
            template: '<ui-view>'
        })
        .state("root.second", {
            abstract: true,
            template: '<ui-view>',
        })
        .state("root.second.a", {
            url: "a",
            template: "second a template",
        })
        .state("root.first", {
            abstract: true,
            template: '<ui-view>'
        })
        .state("root.first.b", {
            url: "b",
            template: "first a template"
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/b");
});


example.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go("root.second.a", {}, {notify: false});
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `notify` to false [prevents the view directive from doing it's job](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1158). Instead of using `notify: false`, which I assume you're doing to avoid the `$stateChangeStart` function, you could conditionally call `$state.go()`.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  if (toState.name !== 'root.second.a') {
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('root.second.a');
  }
});
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/tJPxXGir5YSSPG5jGodn?p=preview

Comment: What if I want to redirect all of the requests? Then what? Also look at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-create-rules-to-prevent-access-to-a-state

Comment: Without `notify: false`, I'll end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: The code I've provided and the plunker link show that it works for all requests and it doesn't end up in an infinite loop. If the destination state is `root.second.a`, the conditional code is not called. Perhaps you should amend your question with more details about your use case because this does not seem ideal.

Comment: So, I only need to make sure that I'm just redirecting requests that are not actually going to destination by default. Correct?

Comment: Yes. But like I said, I don't understand the details about why you would want to do this.

Comment: Never mind, I don't understand it either :) but thanks for the tip.